# NSubstitute: Received() does not check string parameter when string comes from resource

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I use [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) for my [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) tests and try to check if a method is called with the right values. Until know everything works fine. I have to localize the texts and so use resource strings for this. Every unit test now fails, that tests for a method to be recieved, where a string parameter contains a new line.

Here is a simplified example:

```
// Old Version, where the unit test succeed
public void CallWithText(ICallable callable)
{
    callable.ShowText("Some text with a new\nline."); 
}

// New Version, where the unit test fails
// Text of `Properties.Resources.TextWithNewLine` in the
// Resources.resx is "Some text with a new
// line."
public void CallWithText(ICallable callable)
{
    callable.ShowText(Properties.Resources.TextWithNewLine); 
}

[Test]
public void CallWithText_WhenCalled_CallsCallable()
{
    var caller = new Caller();
    var callable = Substitute.For<ICallable>();

    caller.CallWithText(callable);

    callable.Received(1).ShowText("Some text with a new\nline.");
}
```

It seems for me, that there is a problem with the new line. Does anybody has a solution, because it is a mess to adapt all the unit tests.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Also post the output of the test that fails. Are you sure the resource file only contains a single newline and not a linefeed as well?

Comment: You have been right (like @Alexandr Niktin), the resource file contained \r\n and thats the reason the test failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't related to `NSubstitute` but to `String` itself. The new line symbol isn't just `\n`. It's environment specific: `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on Unix, `\r` on early Mac OSes. Please use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add new lines properly in Resource manager.

You have a couple of ways to use:

1. Environment.NewLine property which knows the new line symbol for the current environment:

   ```
   callable.Received(1).ShowText("Some text with a new" + Environment.NewLine + "line.");
   ```
2. Use explicit new line in your expected string:

   ```
   callable.Received(1).ShowText(@"Some text with a new
   line.");
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing exact strings in the unit test will add more maintaining work.
In your case `new line` can be different in different execution environment.

For strings I suggest asserting passed parameter with `Contains` method. Where you can check for the more important words

```cs
[Test]
public void CallWithText_WhenCalled_CallsCallable()
{
    var caller = new Caller();
    var callable = Substitute.For<ICallable>();

    caller.CallWithText(callable);

    callable.Received(1).ShowText(Arg.Is<string>(text => text.Contains("Some text")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This indicates the `Properties.Resources.TextWithNewLine` and `"Some text with a new\nline."` and different. Without knowing too much about `Properties.Resources.TextWithNewLine`, I suggest you try change the test to

```
[Test]
public void CallWithText_WhenCalled_CallsCallable()
{
    var caller = new Caller();
    var callable = Substitute.For<ICallable>();

    caller.CallWithText(callable);

    callable.Received(1).ShowText(Arg.Any<string>());
}
```

Or use the actual string if you really want to assert the content of the string, change to (make sure the resources file is in the test project)

```
[Test]
public void CallWithText_WhenCalled_CallsCallable()
{
    var caller = new Caller();
    var callable = Substitute.For<ICallable>();

    caller.CallWithText(callable);

    callable.Received(1).ShowText(Properties.Resources.TextWithNewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. As the the example is simplified, the value of parameter in the origional example is composite. With the test I also want to test, that the value of the paramter is calculated correctly. So both of your succestions does not work in my case.

Comment: @scher can you provide more information in OP to reflect this?

Comment: Thanks for your work, sorry about my shortcoming explaining the question in detail.